# Need to include AND in the Amount in words in Netsuite (SQL Language)

Tags: javascript, sql, netsuite, suitescript

I am including this formula in the netsuit's field default value:

```
CASE WHEN {total}=0 THEN 'ZERO' 
ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC({total}, 0)),'J'),'JSP') || ' ' || ' ' || ( 
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(TO_CHAR(REGEXP_REPLACE({total}, '^[0-9]+\.', ''))) = 1 THEN 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(REGEXP_REPLACE({total}, '^[0-9]+\.', ''), 0)*10),'J'),'JSP') || 'cents' 
  ELSE  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(REGEXP_REPLACE({total}, '^[0-9]+\.', ''), 0)),'J'),'JSP')  || '&nbsp;FILS ONLY' 
  END)
END
```

If the amount is 6,703.20, than it prints:

```
 SIX THOUSAND SEVEN HUNDRED THREE TWENTY FILS ONLY
```

I want to bring the AND in between to make it show like this:

```
SIX THOUSAND SEVEN HUNDRED THREE and TWENTY FILS ONLY
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, instead of REGEXP_REPLACE, you should use SUBSTR to fetch the results.

Here is an example:

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR({total}),-1 * LENGTH(TO_CHAR({total})),LENGTH(TO_CHAR({total})) - 3),'J'),'JSP') || ' AND ' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR({total}),-2,3),'J'),'JSP')

Define your 'CASE'(s) and in the 'THEN' part, use this formula to get the results.